# Bash: How to add a prefix to a line when a specific number is matched on a line

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a simple problem which I can't seem to find a proper solution for. I have a line with many lines like this:

```
2020-10-07;2020-07-17;954;7004;something;something
2020-10-14;2020-07-16;955;10038;something;something
```

I want to add a prefix `1;` to all lines where the 3rd field is matching `954`, so it ends up like this:

```
1;2020-10-07;2020-07-17;954;7004;something;something
2020-10-14;2020-07-16;955;10038;something;something
```

I have a really bad way of doing this right now with:

```
cat test.csv | awk -F ';' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' | awk '{if($3 == 954) print "1;"$0;}'
```

But, of course, that outputs with spaces as delimiter.

I would really appreciate it if someone has a smarter way of doing this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Awk can do your job easily

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}$3 == 954{print 1,$0;next}1' file

#OR

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}$3 == 954{$0=1 OFS $0}1' file

#OR

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{print ($3==954 ? 1 OFS:"") $0}' file
```

**With your input files:**

```
$ cat file
2020-10-07;2020-07-17;954;7004;something;something 
2020-10-14;2020-07-16;955;10038;something;something

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}$3 == 954{print 1,$0;next}1' file
1;2020-10-07;2020-07-17;954;7004;something;something 
2020-10-14;2020-07-16;955;10038;something;something

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}$3 == 954{$0=1 OFS $0}1' file
1;2020-10-07;2020-07-17;954;7004;something;something 
2020-10-14;2020-07-16;955;10038;something;something

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{print ($3==954 ? 1 OFS:"") $0}' file
1;2020-10-07;2020-07-17;954;7004;something;something 
2020-10-14;2020-07-16;955;10038;something;something
```

**Explanation**

```
awk 'BEGIN{
         FS=OFS=";"       # set input and output field separator
     }
     $3 == 954{           # if 3rd field equal to 954 then
         print 1,$0;      # print 1 and then existing record/row
         next             # go to next line
     }1                   
     '
```

- `$3 == 954{$0=1 OFS $0}1` : if 3rd field equal to 954, modify existing record/row (`$0`), with value `1`, output field separator `OFS` and then existing row/record (`$0`).
- So at the end `}1` :  The 1 at the end of your script is a condition (always true) with no action, so it executes the default action for every line, printing the line (which may have been modified by the previous action in braces)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has worked perfectly for me and I really appreciate the explanation! :)

Comment: Glad to know that it helped. You can accept answer if you think it's solved

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner may help too:

```
awk -F';' '{p=$3==954?"1;":""}{print p$0}' file
```

The reason why you lost the `;` int the output:

If you write `print $1,$2...` awk will use the default `OFS` which is a space. To solve the problem you have basically two ways to go:

1. set `OFS` it is straightforward, as the other answer shows
2. don't set any field, e.g. don't do something like `$2=...`, instead, using `sub()`, `gsub()` to change the text. When you print, don't include comma `,`, just print `$0` concatenating other strings. (my one-liners shows this way)

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`, macthing the 3rd column should be fine but if it is more than say 5 columns, then `awk` is the way.

```sh
sed '/\([^;]*\)\([^;]*\);954[^;]*\(.*\)/s/^/1;/' file.txt
```